# Insert Update Delete in DataTable in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to insert update and delete record using Datatable using gridview(Asp.Net and C#.Net).

DataTable Columns are

1. ID
2. StudentName
3. City

All crud operations(Insert, Update, Delete) operation should be perform using datatable. No database server required.

Comment: have you googled for this

Comment: lots of example on codeproject.com

Comment: yes..all are done using database server.but i need this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding the GridView to the DataTable should let you do all the same operations:

```
myGridView.DataSource = myDataTable;
myGridView.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below link "Asp.net insert, Edit, update, delete data in gridview" which contains the simple program to understand how gridview works and make the columns according to your requirement.

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/02/how-to-inserteditupdate-and-delete-data.html

Note:
 Note Make sure you have used the ID column as DatakeyNames="ID".

Comment: i dont need this one...I want to do with datatable or dataset only...on server needed